# Change password bullets (●) to stars (*)

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to change password input text to stars (*)?

[image]

to

[image]

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to that
You can learn more about HTML inputs

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp